# Avoid duplicating records in loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have two factories for my `Company` and `Employee` models respectively. `Employee` is in a **belongs_to** relationship with `Company`. Here's my two factories:

```
factory :company do
  name "foo company"
end

factory :employee do
  company
  name 'Willy Bytes'      
end
```

There are some occasions where I need to traverse an array of data and populate new `Employee` records accordingly to test against different conditions in my specs. To illustrate, I'm using the following specs to test one of my inclusion validations:

```
it "should be valid if they like red blue or green" do
  ["red","blue","green"].each do |c|
    FactoryGirl.build(:employee, :favourite_colour => c).should be_valid
  end
end

it { FactoryGirl.build(:upload, :favourite_colour => "other").should_not be_valid }
```

However, I have a uniqueness constraint on the parent companies **name** field which yields an error when I attempt to build the record. Is there an intelligent way to resolve/avoid this problem? I run into these types of specs a lot and typically what I would do is define a single `Company` factory and assign that to each record in the loop, but it doesn't feel intuitive and results in a lot of repetition. Is a sequence the only other way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found exactly what I was looking for here: [Find or create record through factory_girl association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145256/find-or-create-record-through-factory-girl-association)

Overriding the default build / new behaviour using the `initialize_with` method seems to be the way to go:

```
factory :company do
 initialize_with { Company.find_or_create_by_name("Foo Company") }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use factory_girl's [sequence generator](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Usage#sequence-and-associations). Your factory will look like this.

```
factory :company do
  sequence(:name) {|n| "company #{n}"}
end
```

Comment: I was hoping that there was a way to avoid creating the excess company records altogether using Factory Girl. I'm almost thinking something along the lines of [find_or_create_by_name](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Accessing+attributes+before+they+have+been+typecasted).

Answer (score 0):

One line:

```
sequence(:name) { |n| "Company #{n}" }
```